# How to build javafx project JAR including created sqlite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx

After exporting project into jar file, the database connection won't work. Is there a way to export the project as a jar file including the SQLite database?

```
Connection dbConnect = null;

try {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    dbConnect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:samples.db");
} catch (Exception e) {
    createNewDatabase("samples.db");
    System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
System.out.println("Opened database successfully");

return dbConnect;
```

Comment: Your code would indicate that you create a new database if one is not available.  If you do that, why then exit the app? and why "export the project as a jar file including the sqlite database"?

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to export your project as a JAR file because that is not well supported for JavaFX programs. Instead you should package your project with jpackage and then including sqlite is also no problem on desktop platforms. (Submitting the result into the Mac AppStore would take a little bit more care but with only a JAR this would not work anyway.)